# How to create date-based ImageView (weekly change)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create an ImageView whose image source changes weekly. I started here, but the app always crashes so unfortunately I can't run it. I searched on GitHub and did not find anything useful. Here is my Java code:

```
package com.zahit.mehmet.onlinetp;

import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Ders_Programi extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ders__programi);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_date);

        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageprogram);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat  mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String strdate = mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
        int currenttime;
        currenttime = Integer.valueOf(strdate.toString());

        textView.setText(strdate.toString());

        if(20160115< currenttime){
            if (currenttime< 20160213) {

                imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filepage33);

            }
            else {

            }

        }
        else {


        }

    }


}
```

And here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.zahit.mehmet.onlinetp.Ders_Programi"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_ders__programi"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textview_date" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageprogram" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "app always crash", post your logcat

Comment: First, fill_parent is deprecated for ages, use match_parent instead. Second, which drawable folder, do you contain your image sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `setBackgroundResource()` call as the logcat says:

```
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatImageView.java:77)
```

Which kind of resource are you trying to load?

Comment: As you say my image resolution is to high. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

From just looking at your source code (without any logcat) I'd say the reason for your crash is a `NullPointerException` because the `Toolbar` can't be found. In the following snippet you are referencing a `Toolbar` with an id of `R.id.toolbar` which is not declared in your layout and thus returning `null`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

So in order to solve your problem you'd have to add a `Toolbar` to your layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

That should fix your issue (again, only if it actually is a `NullPointerException` you are getting, posting the actual logcat would be helpful).